# Move multiple files and sub directories into single directory bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to move everything (every folder and file) in 'test' to 'test2' with a bat script.

This works only for folders, i need it to copy files aswell.

```dos
for /D %%D in ("C:\directory\*.*") do (
        move "%%~D" "D:\directory"
)
```

I also cant use xcopy/robocopy as I need to move not copy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your  code does not show you trying to move from test to test2.  Also, you are mistaken about `ROBOCOPY`.  If you read the help file for the command you would have seen this. `/MOVE :: MOVE files AND dirs (delete from source after copying).`

Comment: /MOVE still copies them, it just deletes the source files after copying.

Comment: What's the difference between copying plus deleting source and moving??

Comment: You appear to be selecting directories containing a period, try removing, **`.*`**.

Comment: @aschipfl moving doesn't write data to the drive, it just changes the location of the file.

Comment: Since you are moving files from one drive to another, the whole data are moved; only if source and destination were on the same drive, the data would be left untouched and only a pointer would be changed.

Comment: @aschipfl im actually moving files on the same drive.

Comment: Hm, `C:` and `D:` are different...

Comment: @aschipfl no way! i screwed the example. I know they're different drives...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work.
first command moves only files, second moves only folders.

```dos
 move C:\test\1\* C:\test\2
    for /D %%D in ("C:\test\1\*") do (
            echo %%~D
            move "%%~D" "C:\test\2"
        )
```